# Is this a valid MySQL injection concern?

Tags: php, security, mysqli, code-injection

Obviously the easiest way in which MySQL injection is used is through GET variables.

However in some of my more complex pages I use PHP Include as such:

```
$template = "template-id";
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mandrill/sender.php");
```

That is *$template* is used in the sender.php file to query a database. Is it a valid concern that a hacker could create a malicious PHP file and include the *sender.php* file and use the *$template* variable to inject code?

Should I be protecting against this or is this over engineering for the majority of use cases?

Comment: What is your threat model?  Does `sender.php` set up a connection using embedded secrets like a DB password, and PHP files authored by an untrusted third-party can load `sender.php`?  Do you need to protect the database from some kind of abuse, like extraction and exfiltration, or modification of sensitive data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of security settings on your server. If it's setup properly, it shouldn't be possible for a hacker to do anything like that.

The two main vulnerabilities would be:

1. If register globals is enabled and you haven't filled `$template` with a value.
2. If you somehow allow unauthorised users to upload their own PHP scripts to your server (which is the only way someone can include your PHP script).

The first one should never be an issue as register globals should *always* be disabled. You should also initialise variables rather than leaving them unset.

The second one is more complex, but shouldn't be an issue unless you've deliberately opened up your security settings. You should normally have suitable file permissions set to prevent Apache (or other webserver user/group) from adding/modifying the main site files, and so on.

With that said, if someone *can* upload their own PHP scripts to your server, then all bets are off. SQL injection becomes irrelevant at that point because they can probably just as easily access the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

*All* dynamically interpolated values must be subject to rigid escaping or binding as parameters. Treat any and all variables as if they contain the plague. Maybe they won't, but it's not going to hurt in order to make sure your *SQL syntax is correct*. That's all "SQL injection prevention" does anyway.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible.

As long as you don't let the user fill `$template` with any kind of input, nothing can happen.

Even though, make sure you don't expose the `sender.php` directly, either via .htaccess or by checking a constant in each file that you set somewhere in your config

Comment: You've missed the point I think. This is to with if the hacker creates a PHP file with that variable in, and includes my sender.php file - then they can set $template to whatever they want

Comment: They can't just include your sender.php file, because it gets parsed by the PHP parser whenever someone else tries to access it via HTTP. They would just be able to get the HTML it produces.
I didn't miss the point, but thanks for that -1 anyways.